# How can I test drag-and-drop functionality between applications?

Tags: cocoa, macos, user-interface, testing, automation

I'm writing a Cocoa app which allows the user to drag content to another application.  I'd like to write an automated GUI test for this behavior.

I can move the mouse cursor using `CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint()`.  How can I issue mousedown and mouseup events to simulate a drag and drop operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CGEventRef down = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(eventSource, kCGEventLeftMouseDown,point, 0);

        CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, down);

        CFRelease(down);
```